# Multiple Key pressed in a console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I've written a text based game and i want to implement a new function for two players
Now when one between up arrow and down arrow is pressed a "spaceship" moves up or down 
I want to duplicate this , but at the same time, i mean , i want to create another spaceship that can moves , now with the "w" and the "s" Key 
How shoul i write a code that can detect two keys pressed at the same time to move the ships at the same time ?
Now i was thinking about using two different readKey but i don't think that can work
Any suggests?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow. I removed c# from the title, since this is what tags are for. Cheers.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964265/handling-more-than-one-keypress-and-detecting-keyup-event

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013087/how-to-detect-multiple-keys-down-onkeydown-event-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider the question of whether you want to go down the concurrent or parallel road of having multiple threads, race conditions and possible deadlocks or do you want to keep your program to one thread and handle things sequentially.

How familiar are you with multi-threading, concurrency, mutexes, locks and other structures in software to prevent problems?

---

Multi-threading would likely be a pretty advanced topic as it would seem like you're still getting used to loops and conditions. Adding in threads and locks can make things pretty complicated quickly.

Comment: I've started programming four months ago at school , i've asked in a new thread because i haven't found a good solution for me . I manage my game with just one while , and i can't put any other things like for while ecc.. So i'm looking for something expecially for a console application not a windows form